# Cannot install mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have followed the instruction below:
https://elixir-lang.org/install.html

but when i try to execute `mix` I see these errors:

```
╰─❯ mix --help
** (Mix) The task "deps.loadpaths" could not be found
```

and

```
╰─❯ mix new app
** (Mix) Application name must start with a letter and have only lowercase letters, numbers and underscore, got: "app". The application name is inferred from the path, if you'd like to explicitly name the application then use the "--app APP" option.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment:  what are the outputs of `which elixir` and `which mix`?

Comment: Also `elixir --version`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have incompatible Erlang/Elixir versions.

Installing with asdf is probably the most reliable way.

- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf
- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang
- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir

Make sure you read the "Before `asdf install`" section of the Erlang asdf plugin.